# Ionic - Google Maps Custom Button

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a google maps page in my ionic 2 app and I want to add a `custom button` to the map(top-left to top-right). On button click I want to call a function in my `Typescript` file. I researched a lot but could not find a good answer. This is what I have till now.

```
initMap = () => {
     let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.563910, 147.154312);

        let mapOptions = {
              center: latLng,
              zoom: 6,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
         }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
}

OnMapButtonClick()
{
   //Do Something
}

(and the html is simple)

    <div [hidden]="!MapView" #map id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a zindexto overlapp

```
    <div [hidden]="!MapView" #map id="map"></div>
    <button class="button button-balanced"   ng-click="do()"   z-index="1000">
```

Comment: worked. Do you have any idea how on button click i can make it full screen? I am using ionic 2 btw